# Git refusing to commit

Tags: github, git-merge, git-branch

I was working to my project and ready to commit my changes but as you can see on the attached photo it seems I've two differents branch on Github.

When I try to commit, it says
"> git pull --tags origin main
From https://github.com/MatteoMammoliti/4Meet---FinalVersion

- branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
  fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories"

I've already tried to use some commands but they haven't worked. Could you please help me?

Already tried to use command I've found here